# Background Timer in PyQt Python Applicatiion

Tags: python, timer, pyqt4

I am Building an application in python using PyQt4. I want to add a background timer to my application so that when the timer runs out, the text editor in my application stops receiving input and freezes up.
I have tried the following method so far:

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()  
    start = time.time()
    #this loop is for the time interval within which the text area of
    #the editor will accept inputs.   
    while time.time() - start < 120:
        pass
    #this will set the text area to a read only state after and will not
    #any more inputs.    
    main.text.setReadOnly(True)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But whenever I run this the application stops responding. I have also tried running the timer through a thread but in that case also the application stops responding.

How can I implement this functionality?

P.S. - I am a Beginner in PyQt.

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text)
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()        
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1080,720)
        self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")
```

This is the watered down version of the main class code. Hope this helps.

Comment: Please post your `class Main` code.

Answer (score 1):

Your application is not responding because you are blocking the event handler. It is processed by `app.exec_()`. This call is only checking for events and handling these in a infinite loop.

Use QTimer with **signal** and **slot**.

[Signals and Slots (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signals_and_slots)

For using signals and slots in pyqt see [this](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

The timer is initialized with a duration and a signal-slot connection. After `app.exec_()` is called, it will wait for the `input_timer` signal `timeout`. If this is raised, the event loop will call lambda function, that disables the textbox, because it is connected to the signal.

```
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()  

    input_timer = QTimer(self)
    input_timer.timeout.connect(lambda : main.text.setReadOnly(True))
    input_timer.setSingleShot(True)
    input_timer.start(2000)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This will disable the textbox after 2000 milliseconds. Adjust as you need. I would move the timer and behaviour to `Main` class.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self,parent)
        self.init_ui()

        self.disable_edit_text_timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.disable_edit_text_timer.timeout.connect(self.disable_edit_text)
        self.disable_edit_text_timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.disable_edit_text_timer.start(2000)

    def init_ui(self):
        self.text = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.text)
        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()        
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1080,720)
        self.setWindowTitle("Text Editor")

    def disable_edit_text(self):
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()  

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Its not working. I tried it again after you edited but still the application crashes.